# SQL SELECT between two tables join by date

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:
1- Settings

```
EffectiveDate  ||     Value
==============================
'2000-01-01'   ||       2
'2005-01-01'   ||       4
'2010-01-01'   ||       6
```

2- DataTable

```
      ID       ||  RecordDate
===============================
       1       ||  '2001-01-01'
       2       ||  '2002-01-01'
       3       ||  '2003-01-01'
       4       ||  '2007-01-01'
       5       ||  '2008-01-01'
       6       ||  '2011-01-01'
       7       ||  '2013-01-01'
       8       ||  '2014-01-01'
```

the relation between these two table is that `EffectiveDate` from `Settings most be smaller(and/or equal) than RecordDate` from `DataTable` but must be the newest one.
for example the result must be something like this:

```
      ID       ||  RecordDate   || value
========================================
       1       ||  '2001-01-01' ||   2
       2       ||  '2002-01-01' ||   2
       3       ||  '2003-01-01' ||   2
       4       ||  '2007-01-01' ||   4
       5       ||  '2008-01-01' ||   4
       6       ||  '2011-01-01' ||   6
       7       ||  '2013-01-01' ||   6
       8       ||  '2014-01-01' ||   6
```

thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` and `TOP` to achieve the desired result:

```
SELECT
    dt.ID, dt.RecordDate, x.Value
FROM DataTable dt
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 Value
    FROM Settings s
    WHERE s.EffectiveDate <= dt.RecordDate
    ORDER BY s.EffectiveDate DESC
) x
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/493308)</kbd>

Comment: Wow!!! Worked!!!
thank you very much for your answer, information, and Online Demo!